# DOM Manipulation to string literal class

Tags: javascript, html, jquery

How can we add classes through javascript/jquery from selecting  String Interpolation class

```
'<input type="checkbox" class="myclass" />'
```

Comment: Create a jQuery object using that string and then call `addClass()`

Answer (score 0):

Does something like this help you out?

HTML

```
<div id="myDiv"></div>
```

CSS

```
.red {
  color: red;
}
```

JavaScript

```
$('#myDiv').append($('<input type="checkbox" class="myclass" id="myCheckbox"/> <label id="myLabel" for="myCheckbox">Check Me</label>').change(function() {
    $("#myLabel").addClass('red');
}));
```